# Body div in css not reading properties properly

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html and css website which was working fine until i updated some content.

The main background is a colour with one image in the top right corner which is in the 'body' div properties. the font family is also in the 'body' properties.

everything else in my website (div layouts, menu bar background image and div back colours etc.) are all displaying ok, but i have no main background and all font is displaying at a small size and as serif when my set font family is san-serif.

```
body{
    min-height:700px;
    min-width:900px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4;
    background-color: #666;
    background-image: url(Images/backleave4.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
```

As its was working just fine before, i assume the issue is that for some reason its not reading all the body properties correctly.If anyone can give me some advice that would be awesome!

Thanks

EDIT:
Over night it somehow fixed itself, for the most part. I don't know what was wrong. Gahh technology!

Comment: Make a jsfiddle if possible, Give me your site link if it is in live. i am not understanding without seeing your output. 

May be somewhere your body properties overridden by other div's properties...

Comment: http://www.johngardinersc.com

Answer (score 0):

Your posted CSS is fine. Can you post a link to the website?

Comment: for me it looks like aspected. There is a Images/backleave4.png in the right corner and the content text has sans-serif. Maybe an issue with your browser cache? Try a hard reload.

Comment: I have deleted my cache in both firefox and safari multiple times and both are displaying the same no background. also the same on my phone (iphone5 safari)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your #rightwrap to-

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
```

I think you want to show your background image all over the page.

Comment: the background of the content divs are a light grey (#F2F2F2) and the main background of the whole page should be dark grey (#666) with one occurrence of the image in the top right corner not repeated all over the page